# How to print no file exists in a directory in node js

Tags: node.js, cron

I made a program with cron npm to copy a file from a directory to another directory once a 5 minute for example if their is no file in source directory it should say no file exists, this is my code

```
const cron = require("node-cron");
const ncp = require('ncp').ncp;
const fs = require("fs");

var source = './temp';
var destination = './lib';

cron.schedule("*/5 * * * *", function () {
    ncp(source, destination, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
        console.log('done!');
    });
});
```

In my case if the process is success its printing Done! and even if thier is no file in the source its printing Done but i want to print No file exists can anyone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, you can use [readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) to check the contents of the source folder. If the files count is greater than 0 copy them, else do nothing.

Hope this answers your question.

```
const cron = require("node-cron");
const ncp = require('ncp').ncp;
const fs = require("fs");

var source = './temp';
var destination = './lib';

cron.schedule("*/5 * * * *", function() {

    fs.readdir(source, function(err, files) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
        if (files.length === 0) {
            console.log('empty folder!');
        } else {
            ncp(source, destination, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.error(err);
                }
                console.log('done!');
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fs.existsSync(path)](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path)

It will return `true` if the path exists, otherwise `false`.

Try this

```
if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
  console.log('No file exists');
}
```